# AngularJS: won't present data in separated file on ng-select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS for creating web app. This is the link which present my full code (example with b.0001.html).
[AngularJS example](https://codio.com/pajsije/AngularJS)

How can I get value ($scope.confirmed in $scope.change function) in controller when user select option data from form? The main problem is that everything works fine if I create one file, but with separated file it won't work, that means if you have one file which include another file with form (using routing in AngularJS).

The form is, which I include in main file with routing mechanism

```
< select ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="change()" id="ng-change-example1">
< option > 11 < /option>
< option > 12 < /option>
< option > 13 < /option>
< option > 14 < /option>
```

```
< input type="checkbox" ng-model="confirmed" id="ng-change-example2" />
< label for="ng-change-example2">Confirmed</label><br />
< tt>debug = {{confirmed}}</tt><br/>
< tt>counter = {{counter}}</tt><br/>

<tt>onchange_var_url = {{myurl}}</tt><br/>

< ul>
  < li ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}
  < /li>
< /ul>
```

Variable *myurl* should get value from user option select, but it doesn't. This is controler

```
angular.module('changeExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {

$scope.counter = 0;

$scope.myurl = 'result from confirmed on change on load: ' + $scope.confirmed;

$scope.change = function() {
    $scope.counter++;

    $scope.myurl = 'result from confirmed on change: ' + $scope.confirmed;

    $http.get("angularjs-data/json-data-0001.json?var=" + $scope.confirmed)
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.names = response.records;
        });
};

}]);
```

Comment: Always add relevant code at SO.

Comment: `ng-model` would help you no ? although i cant see your code !

Comment: Just click on b.0001.html in my Project. Link is: https://codio.com/pajsije/AngularJS

Comment: Post enough code in the question to represent the problem, that is SO policy. we shouldn't have to go to another site or repo and try to figure out what file is what and where the problem code is. Links rot and that repo may also change  rendering this question useless for others in the future

Comment: In controller I can not get value from select option menu $scope.confirmed. When I show result I get undefined.

Comment: First time, you'r select goes from "pristine" to "empty" value... after that, no new changes was detected... I think you should use `ng-option` or set values to your `<option>` tags

Comment: Hi Patrick. $scope.confirmed is in $scope.change function. So, question is how can I get $scope.confirmed value when user select particular data.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comments, I think you just need some value in your `<option>` tags

```js
var apppp = angular.module('apppp', []);

apppp.controller('appppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.count = 0;
  $scope.selectedValue = 10;
  
  $scope.change = function() {
    ++$scope.count;
    $scope.verif1 = $scope.selectedValue;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="apppp" ng-controller="appppCtrl">
  -{{ toto }}-
  
  <select ng-change="change()" ng-model="selectedValue">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
  </select>
  <pre>
  count: {{ count }}
  selectedValue: {{ selectedValue }}
  </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are read carefully you will see that I already use ng-model. < select ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="change()" id="ng-change-example1">

Comment: And if you read the code carefully, you'll see that my `option`s get a value :-) That's the point, the ng-model will get the selected value, if exists

Comment: Yes, but this for is separeted file & I get the same result if it is in one file like yours. Problem is, if it is in separeted file it wont work as I mention before.

Comment: I use angular-route and routing method to include specific file with form which will present data on user select option. You can see my full code by clicking on the link in my question from the begining.

Comment: Also, this example that I gave here is the simplest example which include desired form file in main html file. So, the form with select option is included in main html file. When form is a part of main html file, script work well like yours.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the answer to what you asked. The solution is to put selected value in change function. What you gonna do is to put selected value in the change function on this way:

```
< select ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="change(confirmed)">
< option > 11 < /option>
< option > 12 < /option>
< option > 13 < /option>
< option > 14 < /option>
< /select>
```

and in controller you must change function on this way:

```
scope.change = function(selected_value) {
    $scope.myurl = 'result from confirmed on change: ' + $scope.confirmed;
}
```

That's all. Thanks for your attention & Best Regards.

Comment: Hi Alex, this is right answer. Now everything works well. It was pretty simple.